# Is there something you can do with broken weapons?

Tags: baldurs-gate

Welp, a two handed sword broke after using it too much, and thereafter a new item appears called "broken weapon".

Is there something I can do with a "broken weapon"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every iron o steel weapon will break because of the iron crisis if not enchanted or if you are not using any mod.

You can discard it, the broken weapon can't be reforged, recycled or sold and has no value in the game at this point, except for item collectors (in un-modded Baldur's Gate anyway).
http://baldursgate.wikia.com/wiki/Broken_Weapon

Comment: Where can I find an item collector?

Comment: My bad! I was playing HotS while answering this.
"You can discard it, because it can't be reforged, recycled or sold and has no value in the game at this point"

Comment: Yeah but in the article says that item collectors are the exception. Where can I find them?

Comment: I think it's talking about the player. I can't remember if there is a quest to collect them without mods. I found nothing about it in the wikis and faqs.

Comment: In vanilla Baldur's Gate broken weapons have no value whatsoever.